# What does this mean in the Observable TC-39 proposal?

Tags: javascript, observable, combinators

In the [TC-39 Observable API proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable) I see:

> Compositional: Observables can be composed with higher-order combinators.

A combinator is a function that can be used to combine two (or more?) logic pieces into single, more useful construct.

So what does the above quote mean in the context of observables?

Comment: If you scroll a bit further down, they give an example - Ctrl+F for *We can then use standard combinators*.

Comment: TL;DR - it's referring to functions like `filter`, `map` and `flatMap` that allow you to transform one kind of observable into another.

Comment: OK thanks. I will accept as the answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinators, in the context of Observables, refer to the functions (usually attached to `Observable.prototype`, in the implementations I've seen) that allow you to transform one kind of Observable into another. There's a good example a little bit further down in the proposal:

```
// Return an observable of special key down commands
function commandKeys(element) {
    let keyCommands = { "38": "up", "40": "down" };

    return listen(element, "keydown")
        .filter(event => event.keyCode in keyCommands)
        .map(event => keyCommands[event.keyCode])
}
```

In this example, `filter` and `map` are the combinators - they work in a similar fashion to the functions of the same name on `Array.prototype`. The important thing to note is that, similarly to the array functions, they **always return a new Observable** - they do not mutate the existing one. This is useful, because it means that further combinators could be chained on to the result of `commandKeys` if necessary.